# Where is symmetry condition used in the proof of Banach fixed point theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I was learning the proof of Banach fixed point theorem from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

I am wondering where is the symmetry condition $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ used in the proof?

Comment: Is there any good reason to believe that it must be used?

Comment: Just curious! So Banach fixed point theorem is true in the metric spaces where symmetry condition is not satisfied?

Comment: Is the symmetry condition not just an axiom of a metric space? It's part of the definition of a metric, not every fact about a metric space must be used in a proof about metric spaces.

Comment: @LoganM the point of OP then, I imagine, is this: Assuming the symmetry condition of metric spaces is *not* used in the Banach fixed-point theorem, then if we defined a new structure similar to that of a metric space but without the symmetry axiom, then this structure would satisfy the Banach fixed-point theorem also.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, that is what I mean. Google search shows such metric spaces are called quasi-metric pr asymmetric spaces.

Comment: @AdamRubinson In that case that would indeed be a reasonable assumption, and indeed true.

Comment: Good question. Metric spaces without symmetry were studied quite a bit so maybe someone tried it already.

Comment: I'm not sure but this seems relevant: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82280321.pdf

Comment: Actually disregard my last comment, it might not be so (though I guess if I interpret it to be that the symmetry of metrics bears no importance in the proof whatsoever) I think the most direct area to look into would be on the properties that complete quasimetric spaces have, and this paper https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81975803.pdf could have something of interest?